# Best practice to handle release/debug libraries in cmake find module

Tags: windows, cmake

I'm trying to write a cmake find module for an external library and also make this work under Windows. The library has different paths for compiled versions with debug and release flags (-MD and -MDd) and also for different compiler versions. For example, there are the following paths:

```
C:/cplex/lib/x86_windows_vs2012/stat_mda/cplex1262.lib
C:/cplex/lib/x86_windows_vs2012/stat_mdd/cplex1262.lib
C:/cplex/lib/x86_windows_vs2013/stat_mda/cplex1262.lib
C:/cplex/lib/x86_windows_vs2013/stat_mdd/cplex1262.lib
```

What is the best practice to handle this in a find module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The release and debug versions can be handled in two different ways, depending on whether you provide an `IMPORTED` library or only a list of files in the `CPLEX_LIBRARIES` variable:

- for the `IMPORTED` library you should use the `install(...EXPORT...)` cand `install(EXPORT ...)` commands which handle this automatically by setting the appropriate config-dependent property on the `IMPORTED` target (like, `IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG` and `IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE`)
- if your find-module provides only variables, like `CPLEX_LIBRARIES` you can use the `debug` and `optimized` specifiers:

  ```
  set(CPLEX_LIBRARIES optimized <path-to-release.lib> debug <path-to-debug.lib>)
  ```

To select between vs2012 and vs2013 versions your find-module should query the variables `MSVC11` and `MSVC12`.

For other flags see the Boost find-module for conventions.

I would also recommend to write a config-module instead of a find-module.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to cmake and compiling under Windows. I'm not sure what an IMPORTED library  would look like, currently I just  add paths to CPLEX_LIBRARIES. I think I also have to use install to get the dll file into the build directory, correct? Whats the difference between a config-module and a find-module? Could you point me to some documentation for that?

Comment: install: yes, but files should be installed into the install directory the path stored in the variable CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX. You need to set this variable when you configure your project (I mean, don't set it in the CMakeLists.txt). For the `install` command you specify paths relative to CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX

Comment: find/config-module: a find module is installed to some central location, independently from the actual package. For example, FindZLIB is shipped in the CMake distribution, not with ZLIB. It must be prepared to look for ZLIB in every possible location ZLIB can be, it must work on every system with various ZLIB builds.

Comment: On the other hand a config-module is shipped with the actual product. Can be much simpler since it is built along with the product so it knows where to look for the libraries, headers.

Comment: When you call `find_package` it usually looks for a find-module, if not found, looks for the config-module.

Comment: imported library: it's a target, just like what you create with add_library(). But unlike a normal target library, imported libraries are not built in the actual project, they are proxy-like objects which contains information about a library installed by another project.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I cannot ship the module with the product. The module is for a third-party library (Cplex) that does not come with any find/config modules as far as I know. I will look into IMPORTED libraries, it seems like a better fit.

Comment: I have found the docs for config module and find module to be utterly worthless. Best to just avoid cmake if possible.